# Is it possible to pass a Mat4 as float pointer in rust 'glam' crate to Opengl call gl::UniformMatrix4fv?

Tags: opengl, rust

I'm learning rust using opengl.  I'm using the 'gl' crate for opengl specifically. I'm using the 'glam' crate for 3d math. The last argument of the function gl::UniformMatrix4fv() looks for is of type *const GLfloat.  I've tried:

```
    let mut transform = Mat4::IDENTITY;
    transform = transform * Mat4::from_translation(Vec3::new(0.5, 0.5, 0.0));
    transform = transform * Mat4::from_axis_angle(Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), window.get_time());

    let transform_loc = gl::GetUniformLocation(shader.id, CString::new("transform").unwrap().as_ptr());
    gl::UniformMatrix4fv(transform_loc, 1, gl::FALSE, transform as *const f32);
```

However glam implements Mat4 as a struct. The above code panics with "non-primitive cast: glam::Mat4 as *const f32" error.

Without the casting the error is of "mismatched types.  expected *-ptr, found 'glam::Mat4' expected raw pointer *const f32 found struct glam::Mat4"

Looking over the documentation I don't see any functions that will return a pointer to the Matrix data.  Any help or turn to the proper direction will be greatly appreciated.  If not possible, I will try a different crate.

Comment: You might have to store the array returned by [`Mat4::to_cols_array`](https://docs.rs/glam/0.16.0/glam/f32/struct.Mat4.html#method.to_cols_array) in a local variable and pass in a pointer to this array.

Comment: Thanks this worked! I changed the transform argument to &transform.to_cols_array()[0] .Would you like to post as a formal answer, so that I can give you credit?

Comment: No worries! No need for that, please go ahead and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit to a comment by EvilTak.

glam has a method to_col_array() that returns the data in the Mat4.

issue solved by changing:

```
gl::UniformMatrix4fv(transform_loc, 1, gl::FALSE, transform as *const f32);
```

to

```
gl::UniformMatrix4fv(transform_loc, 1, gl::FALSE, &transform.to_cols_array()[0]);
```